# Can't get user data after logging in Firebase React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to create a social media app with React Native / Expo and Firebase, and I have successfully been able to create accounts and login, but I am still trying to figure out how to get user data such as username when the user logs in. Basically, when I log in or create an account, I want the profile page to show the username and profile picture associated with the user that logged in, but I'm not sure how to do that. It probably has something to do with the AuthStateChanged() function or something like that, but I'm not sure.

Here is my App.js file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { LogBox, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Feather from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather'
import { useFonts, Nunito_400Regular as NunitoRegular, Nunito_700Bold as NunitoBold } from '@expo-google-fonts/nunito';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigator from './src/navigation/index';

import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB1TxcRpLQq0Zqs0f0FvPitIto0tZo_0xM",
  authDomain: "shutter-42e70.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "shutter-42e70",
  storageBucket: "shutter-42e70.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "149059508529",
  appId: "1:149059508529:web:0dbc5bbbb75bf022ef7810"
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

// The theme we'll be using for our navigator
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: '#FAFAFA'
  },
};

// Loads the Feather icons (https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/)
function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default function App() {

  const [assetsReady, setAssetsReady] = useState(false);

  async function _loadFonts() {
    const iconFontAssets = cacheFonts([Feather.font])
    await Promise.all([...iconFontAssets]);
  }

  // Loads the Nunito font (https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/)
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    NunitoRegular, NunitoBold
  });

  // If the fonts or assets are not loaded, we show a default App Loading screen.
  // Otherwise, we return our Photo Sharing App!
  if (!fontsLoaded || !assetsReady) {
    return <AppLoading
              startAsync={_loadFonts}
              onFinish={() => setAssetsReady(true)}
              onError={console.warn}
            />
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
      <Navigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my Login.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import theme from '../../assets/themes';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { Octicons, Fontisto } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Separator from './Separator';
import KeyBoardAvoidingWrapper from './KeyboardAvoidingWrapper';
import firebase from 'firebase';

var errorMsg = '...'

const Login = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <KeyBoardAvoidingWrapper>
            <View>
                <View style = {styles.StyledContainer}>
                    <View style = {styles.InnerContainer}>
                        <Image style = {styles.PageLogo} resizeMode = "cover" source = {require('./../../assets/images/logo.png')} />
                        <Text style = {styles.PageTitle}>Shutter</Text>
                        <Text style = {styles.TagLine}>Social Media for Photographers</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <Formik
                    initialValues = {{email: '', password: ''}}
                    onSubmit = {(values) => {
                        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
                        .then((result) => {
                            navigation.navigate('Feed');
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            alert(error)
                    })
                }}
                >
                    {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values}) => (
                        <View style = {styles.styledFormArea}>
                            <MyTextInput
                                label = " "
                                icon = "mail"
                                placeholder = "email@email.com"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('email')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('email')}
                                value = {values.email}
                                keyboardType = "email-address"
                            />

                            <MyTextInput
                                label = " "
                                icon = "lock"
                                placeholder = "password"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('password')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('password')}
                                value = {values.password}
                                secureTextEntry = {true}
                            />

                            <Text style = {styles.msgBox}>{errorMsg}</Text>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleSubmit} style = {styles.loginButton}>
                                <Text style = {styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <Separator />

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleSubmit} style = {styles.googleSigninButton}>
                                <Fontisto name = "google" color = {theme.colors.white} size = {25} ></Fontisto>
                                <Text style = {styles.googleSigninButtonText}>Sign in with Google</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <View style = {styles.signupLinkView}>
                                <Text style = {styles.signupText}>Don't have an account? </Text>
                                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.signupLinkButton}>
                                    <Text onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Sign Up')} style = {styles.signupLinkText}>Sign up</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </View>
        </KeyBoardAvoidingWrapper>
    );
};

const MyTextInput = ({label, icon, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style = {styles.leftIcon}>
                <Octicons name = {icon} size = {30} color = {theme.colors.primary} />
            </View>
            <Text style = {styles.styledTextInput}>{label}</Text>
            <TextInput style = {styles.textInput} {...props} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    StyledContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing.m,
        paddingTop: theme.spacing.l,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
        marginTop: 80,
    },
    InnerContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    PageLogo: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },
    PageTitle: {
        ...theme.textVariants.h1,
        marginTop: theme.spacing.m,
    },
    TagLine: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,

    },
    styledFormArea: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: theme.spacing.l,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    leftIcon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 1,
        marginTop: 28,
        marginLeft: 12,
    },
    styledTextInput: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
    },
    textInput: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingLeft: 50,
        paddingRight: theme.spacing.l,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
    },
    loginButton: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
    },
    loginButtonText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body2,
        color: theme.colors.white,
    },
    msgBox: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    googleSigninButton: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 16,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
    },
    googleSigninButtonText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body2,
        color: theme.colors.white,
        paddingLeft: 25,
    },
    signupLinkView: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing.sm,
    },
    signupText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
    },
    signupLinkButton: {

    },
    signupLinkText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
        opacity: 0.6,
    },
})

export default Login;
```

Here is my Signup.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import theme from '../../assets/themes';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Separator from './Separator';
import KeyboardAvoidingWrapper from './KeyboardAvoidingWrapper';
import firebase from 'firebase';

var errorMsg = '...'

const SignUp = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
            <View>
                
                <View style = {styles.StyledContainer}>
                    <View style = {styles.InnerContainer}>
                        <Image style = {styles.PageLogo} resizeMode = "cover" source = {require('./../../assets/images/logo.png')} />
                        <Text style = {styles.PageTitle}>Shutter</Text>
                        <Text style = {styles.TagLine}>Social Media for Photographers</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <Formik
                initialValues = {{fullName: '', email: '', username: '', password: '', confirmPassword: ''}}
                onSubmit = {(values) => {
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
                    .then((result) => {
                        firebase.firestore().collection("users")
                            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                            .set({
                                fullName: values.fullName,
                                displayName: values.email,
                                username: values.username,
                                password: values.password,
                            })
                        if (values.password === values.confirmPassword)
                            navigation.navigate('Signup Options')
                        else
                            errorMsg = 'Passwords do not match'
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        alert(error)
                    })
                }}
                >
                    {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values}) => (
                        <View style = {styles.styledFormArea}>
                            <MyTextInput
                                label = "Name"
                                icon = "person"
                                placeholder = "John Doe"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('fullName')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('fullName')}
                                value = {values.fullName}
                            />

                            <MyTextInput
                                label = "Email"
                                icon = "mail"
                                placeholder = "email@email.com"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('email')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('email')}
                                value = {values.email}
                                keyboardType = "email-address"
                            />


                            <MyTextInput
                                label = "Username"
                                icon = "person"
                                placeholder = "username"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('username')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('username')}
                                value = {values.username}
                            />

                            <MyTextInput
                                label = "Password"
                                icon = "lock"
                                placeholder = "password"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('password')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('password')}
                                value = {values.password}
                                secureTextEntry = {true}
                            />

                            <MyTextInput
                                label = "Confirm Password"
                                icon = "lock"
                                placeholder = "retype password"
                                placeholderTextColor = {theme.colors.black}
                                onChangeText = {handleChange('confirmPassword')}
                                onBlur = {handleBlur('confirmPassword')}
                                value = {values.confirmPassword}
                                secureTextEntry = {true}
                            />

                            <Text style = {styles.msgBox}>{errorMsg}</Text>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleSubmit} style = {styles.loginButton}>
                                <Text style = {styles.loginButtonText}>Sign Up</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <Separator />

                            <View style = {styles.signupLinkView}>
                                <Text style = {styles.signupText}>Already have an account? </Text>
                                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.signupLinkButton}>
                                    <Text onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Login')} style = {styles.signupLinkText}>Login</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
    );
};

const onSignUp = ({values}) => {
    console.log(values);
}

const MyTextInput = ({label, icon, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.inputFieldView}>
            <View style = {styles.leftIcon}>
                <Octicons name = {icon} size = {30} color = {theme.colors.primary} />
            </View>
            <Text style = {styles.styledTextInput}>{label}</Text>
            <TextInput style = {styles.textInput} {...props} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    StyledContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing.m,
        paddingTop: theme.spacing.l,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
        marginTop: 80,
    },
    InnerContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    PageLogo: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },
    PageTitle: {
        ...theme.textVariants.h1,
        marginTop: theme.spacing.m,
    },
    TagLine: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,

    },
    inputFieldView: {
        marginTop: 12,
    },
    styledFormArea: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: theme.spacing.l,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    leftIcon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 1,
        marginTop: 28,
        marginLeft: 12,
    },
    styledTextInput: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
    },
    textInput: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingLeft: 50,
        paddingRight: theme.spacing.l,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
    },
    loginButton: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.m,
    },
    loginButtonText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body2,
        color: theme.colors.white,
    },
    msgBox: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    signupLinkView: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing.sm,
    },
    signupText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
    },
    signupLinkButton: {

    },
    signupLinkText: {
        ...theme.textVariants.body3,
        opacity: 0.6,
    },
})

export default SignUp;
```

Sorry if my code isn't written very well and isn't very organized. I couldn't find very many good tutorials on firebase authentication so this is what I came up with after watching like 5 different firebase authentication tutorials lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, here is the link to my github repo if you want to see my entire project file: [github repo](https://github.com/bpyle02/Photo-Sharing-App)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use redux or React hooks to save user info into global state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

In the callback of signInWithEmailAndPassword() return user profile data

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in 
  var user = userCredential.user;
  /*  user: 
      - email
      - uid
      - displayName
      - emailVerified
      - phoneNumber
      - photoURL
      - metadata
      ...
 
  */
})
.catch((error) => {
  // catch error
});
```

Then in your components/screens, you can call the state to show user's data.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. I'll try this out!

Comment: Ok so the implementation is working so far, but how would i use a hook to make the user variable global? Sorry I'm kind of a noob

Comment: You should read 2 links above & try to search some example repository on GitHub. Here is an example [https://github.com/9kmmr/react-native-firebase-noob-example](https://github.com/9kmmr/react-native-firebase-noob-example)